# How do I customise a preference to display a time picker widget through XML

Tags: android, xml, android-preferences

Firstly I'd like to say that I have only been working on Android for about a week now, so I guess you can consider me a newb! Therefore I apologise in advance if the solution is overly simple, but I can assure you that I have done my research before posting here, and haven't found an appropriate solution as of yet (or maybe I have and don't fully realise it!). Nonetheless, having lots of fun and just want to solve this problem and learn, so here goes...

**The Application**

The application I am developing is essentially a reminder service, and I am currently working on the **preferences** screen.

**The Problem**

I would like the user to be able to specifiy a time when he/she will be reminded daily. I want this selection to be done via the preferences screen. This is how my preferences screen looks so far...

[My preferences screen](http://img87.imageshack.us/img87/3129/preferencesm.png)

**My Question**

Ideally, whenever the user selects the "Alarm Time" preference, I would like the following to appear (this is a screenshot of a preference from another application - PillReminder).

[Preference with Time Picker widget (taken from another app - "PillReminder")](http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/2366/timepickerwidget.png)

My question is, what is the best way to create this? I really want to keep all the visual aspects of the application **using only XML**, therefore I don't want a Java solution. Is this possible or am I completely off track? Other potential solutions I have heard of are using themes, alert dialogs and extending preference classes etc. Maybe some of these are correct, but I am unsure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks! :)

Comment: Look at this link: http://www.twodee.org/blog/?p=1037 There you have an explanation with sample of how create a custom DialogPreferences where you set a date. Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, what is the best way to create this?

That is probably a custom `DialogPreference` that happens to have a `TimePicker` in it.

> I really want to keep all the visual aspects of the application using only XML, therefore I don't want a Java solution.

Custom preferences like this cannot be defined in XML. You will need to create a subclass of `DialogPreference`, define what goes in the dialog, and how the dialog's contents can be stored to (and retrieved from) a `SharedPreference` value.

My [ColorMixer CWAC project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-colormixer) has a `ColorPreference` that you may wish to examine.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your response (haven't seemed to be getting any from other forums haha). I will read into this and take a stab at it... wish me luck! Thanks again.